Is there any situation where re.search could not be used instead of re.match?
The documentation seems clear but it begs the question, what is the purpose of re.match? Couldn't re.search with the caret (^) be used instead as long as the MULTILINE flag is not enabled? Is re.match added just to make validation easier and not having to write caret at the beginning all the time?
Is there any difference how re.search('^test \w+', 'test example') and re.match('test \w+', 'test example') processed? The resulting matches seem to be the same, although it is hard to properly evaluate that, since Match object does not have the __eq__ method implemented.
If we can believe this StackOverflow user, then re.match does not even provide any performance benefits. What is the point of it then? Just to help readability?

This is covered in the docs search() vs. match():
In MULTILINE mode match() only matches at the beginning of the string, whereas using search() with a regular expression beginning with '^' will match at the beginning of each line.
>>> re.match("X", "A\nB\nX", re.MULTILINE)  # No match
>>> re.search("^X", "A\nB\nX", re.MULTILINE)  # Match
<re.Match object; span=(4, 5), match='X'>


Couldn't re.search with the caret (^) be used instead as long as the MULTILINE flag is not enabled?

Yes.

Even in MULTILINE mode, \A can be used to only match at the start of a string with re.search.
